# Insert an image in a column of a table that already has 5 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I want to insert an image in a column of a table that already has 5 columns

some thing like this code 
but it doesn-t work so im askin you if there is any solution

```
insert into dbo.Produit 
values
('Pc portable',
 'HP EliteBook série p',
 'Un ordinateur professionnel robuste de 35,5 et 39,6 cm (14.0" et 15.6") à fonctions multiples, hautes performances et longue autonomie',
 SELECT * FROM 
 OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Users\Yassine-Kira\Desktop\Templates\ProductImg\elite-book_tcm_133_1096796.png', SINGLE_BLOB) ,20,4999,0);
```

Comment: That is nice.  Do you have a question?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for.  Please rephrase your question so that we know what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do that the way you're trying, Why don't you load the image into a variable then use that variable in your insert statement:

```
declare @image varbinary(max)

set @image = (SELECT BulkColumn from Openrowset( Bulk 'C:\Users\Yassine-Kira\Desktop\Templates\ProductImg\elite-book_tcm_133_1096796.png', Single_Blob) as BikeImage)

insert into dbo.Produit 
values
('Pc portable',
 'HP EliteBook série p',
 'Un ordinateur...',
 @image,
 20,
 4999,
 0);
```

Comment: they show me this erreur msg Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 5
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: @YassineKira What is the data type of the image column in your table?

Comment: @YassineKira Great! Please mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark. More info here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work